# Is there a way to optimize the query for this piece of code؟

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

I want that when the user gets the messages of a page, the field **seen** of all unread messages should be set to True
Is there a way to **improve** and **optimize** this code below?

I have 4 table (user, room, message, seen)

One user can have several rooms and one room can have several users
A user can send several messages and a message can only be related to a specific user
And one message can be seen by several users (seen table)

models.py file:

```
class User(models.Model):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      date_join = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.username}|{self.is_admin}"

class Room(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="rooms")


     def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.name}"

class Message(models.Model):
      content = models.TextField()
      seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="messages")
      room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="room_messages")
      replied_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, 
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


      def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.user.id}: {self.content} [{self.created_at}]"

class Seen(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="seens")
      date_seen = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py file:

```
class MessageViewSet(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if self.kwargs.get("room_pk"):
            queryset = queryset.filter(room_id=self.kwargs.get("room_pk"))

        filter_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(filter_queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            response = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            for message in page:
                if message.user.id != self.request.user.id:
                    if not message.seens.select_related("message").select_related("user").filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).exists():

                        message.seen = True
                        seen_obj = Seen()
                        seen_obj.user = self.request.user
                        seen_obj.message = message
                        seen_obj.save()
                        message.seens.add(seen_obj)
                        message.save()
                else:
                    continue
            return response
```

Comment: The modeling itself looks odd: your `Seen` has a `ForeignKey` message, but `message` seems to have an m2m to `Seen`s as well?

Comment: Probably it would help if you share the models itself.

Comment: @Willem VO supports mod strike Hi Willem, I put the model file and yes, the models have a strange relationship due to the ability to be seen by several users.
I would be very grateful if you could help me
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the item to the `seens`, this is just the reverse relation of the `ForeignKey`, so it will be added "implicitly". Another problem is that you each time make a query to check if the message has been seen, you can annotate that once with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries), furthermore you can boost efficiency significantly by constructing the `Seen` objects in bulk:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


class MessageViewSet(
    ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, GenericViewSet
):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().annotate(
            is_seen=Exists(
                Seen.objects.filter(
                    message_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=request.user.pk
                )
            )
        )
        if 'room_pk' in self.kwargs:
            queryset = queryset.filter(room_id=self.kwargs['room_pk'])

        filter_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(filter_queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            response = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            Seen.objects.bulk_create(
                [
                    Seen(user=self.request.user, message=message)
                    for message in page
                    if message.user_id != self.request.user.id
                    and not message.is_seen
                ]
            )
            return response
```

This will inspect and create `Seen` objects all in only one extra query.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem, this is really a very good solution
Yes, I know, I just made a simple user model for testing
I changed some codes, such as the seen field, which does not change to True when Seen is created
I converted this field to a method that counts the number of seens of a message
can I ask a question?
Honestly, I just entered the world of programming and I wanted to see if I could get help and advice from you
Maybe through gmail?